# Does Lego intervention improve children's completion score compared to normal SALT interventions?

Tags: learning, communication, speech, cognitive-development

I'm working with a child who refuses to perform any SLT activities without the aid of Lego. I was wondering if anyone knew any interesting interventions involving Lego compared to standard SALT techniques.